# How to organize html and css to do this UI design with responsive design

Tags: html, css

I have a design which need to convert to html+css and want to make it work on all screen sizes, so need to be responsive.
The initial UI is like this:
[image]
Then when user click on one of these boxes it should expand a details container below, like this:
[image]

And when screen get smaller on a mobile device for example it should look like this:
[image]

each box of these boxes should open different details container when user click on it.

What i did is puting each row of boxes in a a new ul element and after each ul a new ul with details containers, and using js I open the correct details container.
These issue I am facing now is on small screens, when user click on a box the details appears after the fifth element not just below and this is not correct.
[image]

Also I tried to put inside each box its details container and show when click, but the issue is that appears like this:
[image]

Seams I am thinking wrong about this design, so if someone have examples or ideas to achieve this, please advice.

HTML i wrote:

```
<div class="everything">
        <ul class="services-row">
            <li class="">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">1</a>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">2</a>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">3</a>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">4</a>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">5</a>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="service-content">
            <div class="">
                <i class="closeService">X</i>
                <p>
                    <img class="pull-left" style="margin-right:20px;" src="#" />
                    <span>Details</span>
                    Some Details
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <i class="closeService">X</i>
                <p>
                    <img class="pull-left" style="margin-right:20px;" src="#" />
                    <span>Details</span>
                    Some Details
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <i class="closeService">X</i>
                <p>
                    <img class="pull-left" style="margin-right:20px;" src="#" />
                    <span>Details</span>
                    Some Details
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <i class="closeService">X</i>
                <p>
                    <img class="pull-left" style="margin-right:20px;" src="#" />
                    <span>Details</span>
                    Some Details
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <i class="closeService">X</i>
                <p>
                    <img class="pull-left" style="margin-right:20px;" src="#" />
                    <span>Details</span>
                    Some Details
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="services-row even">
            <li class="">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">6</a>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">7</a>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">8</a>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">9</a>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">10</a>
                    <i></i>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="service-content">
            <div class="">
                <i class="closeService">X</i>
                <p>
                   <img class="pull-left" style="margin-right:20px;" src="#" />
                    <span>Details</span>
                    Some Details
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <i class="closeService">X</i>
                <p>
                    <img class="pull-left" style="margin-right:20px;" src="#" />
                    <span>Details</span>
                    Some Details
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <i class="closeService">X</i>
                <p>
                    <img class="pull-left" style="margin-right:20px;" src="#" />
                    <span>Details</span>
                    Some Details
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <i class="closeService">X</i>
                <p>
                    <img class="pull-left" style="margin-right:20px;" src="#" />
                    <span>Details</span>
                    Some Details
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="" >
                <i class="closeService">X</i>
                <p>
                    <img class="pull-left" style="margin-right:20px;" src="#" />
                    <span>Details</span>
                    Some Details
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And complete sample: http://jsfiddle.net/J2w4T/2/

Comment: You haven't tried anything yourself?

Comment: Can you add more detail to the JSFiddle? There seems to be insufficient/broken structure for any interactivity.

Comment: updated: http://jsfiddle.net/J2w4T/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use descriptive class names instead number names, and second, related to your questions, you can use FlexBox instead display table and float, I work in a implementation of this code on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7FLnL/4/,

```
ul {
        display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
        display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
        display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
        display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
        display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
```

this code have litle bugs in last item, but it's nothing that you can't fix.